# How do I add 2 textboxes in the same with a max of 10 rows with incrementing IDs that I can remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I am working on a project that has to be done entirely in HTML, JavaScript and jQuery because I don't have access to the internet or server.  I need to add 2 textboxes that appear in a single row at a time, and when the "Add More"  button is clicked, it adds another row of two textboxes but does NOT go past 10 rows at any given time.  Both textboxes have to share a different ID but with the same numerical value at the end of the ID since that is the only way I can capture the values of the textboxes.  Also, I need a "Remove" link that will remove each row individually, and a way to remove the ENTIRE group when the "No" radio button is clicked.

The way I have it now, it does ALMOST all of that, except there is ONE big glitch.  If the user clicks the "Remove" link on any one of the rows, and then decides to click the "No" radio button, but then decides to click the "Yes" radio button to start over, when they click the "Add More" button, it will display 2 rows at a time instead of just one at a time.  If they repeat that process again, it will then display 3 rows at a time when the "Add More" button is clicked.  I was able to determine, after repeating that process enough times, it seems to IGNORE the max length.

Below is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>

  <style>
    .inp {
      width: 40%;
    }
    .remove {
      float: right;
      color: blue;
      font-size: 10px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #FFF;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.test_list').hide();

      $('#test_yes').click(function() {
        $('.test_list').show();

        var test_max_fields = 10;
        var test_x = 0;
        $('#test_add').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (test_x < test_max_fields) {
            test_x++;
            var inps = $('#test_wrapper >div:last').data('count') + 1 || 5;
            $('#test_wrapper').append('<div class="test" data-count="' + inps + '"><input type="text" name="test_textbox_1" id="test_textbox_1' + inps + '" class="inp"/> $<input type="text" name="test_textbox_2" id="test_textbox_2' + inps + '" class="inp"/><a class=remove>Remove</a><br><br></div>');
          } else {
            var inps = " ";
          }
        });

        $('#test_wrapper').on('click', 'a.remove', function() {
          $(this).closest('div').remove();
        });
      });

      $('#test_no').click(function() {
        $('.test').remove();
        $('.test_list').hide();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr class="test_main">
      <td>
        Do you want to test this?
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="test_check" id="test_yes" value="Yes">
        <label>No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="test_check" id="test_no" value="No">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test_list" style="line-height:1em;">
      <td>
        Press the ADD MORE button
      </td>
      <td>
        Textbox 1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Textbox 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test_list" style="line-height:1em;">
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="test_wrapper">      
     </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test_list">
      <td>
        &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>
        <button id="test_add">Add More</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tabel>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use a div for the rows with 100% width. Insider the div float the boxes. Use a contents to check how man rows are added. I think your counter is wrong. Please Check it. You do Not decrease it.

Comment: maybe you should reset the counter when you delete everything as suggested above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test the following code.it's working perfectly for me

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>

  <style>
    .inp {
      width: 40%;
    }
    .remove {
      float: right;
      color: blue;
      font-size: 10px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #FFF;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.test_list').hide();


      $('#test_yes').click(function() {
        $('.test_list').show();
      });


      var test_max_fields = 10;
      test_x = 0;

      $('#test_add').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (test_x < test_max_fields) {
          test_x++;
          var inps = $('#test_wrapper >div:last').data('count') + 1 || 5;
          $('#test_wrapper').append('<div class="test" data-count="' + inps + '"><input type="text" name="test_textbox_1" id="test_textbox_1' + inps + '" class="inp"/> $<input type="text" name="test_textbox_2" id="test_textbox_2' + inps + '" class="inp"/><a class=remove>Remove</a><br><br></div>');

        } else {
          var inps = "";
        }
      });

      $('#test_wrapper').on('click', 'a.remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
      });


      $('#test_no').click(function() {
        $('#test_wrapper').empty();
        $('.test_list').hide();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr class="test_main">
      <td>
        Do you want to test this?
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="test_check" id="test_yes" value="Yes">
        <label>No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="test_check" id="test_no" value="No">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test_list" style="line-height:1em;">
      <td>
        Press the ADD MORE button
      </td>
      <td>
        Textbox 1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Textbox 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test_list" style="line-height:1em;">
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="test_wrapper">                        
                </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test_list">
      <td>
        &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>
        <button id="test_add">Add More</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tabel>
</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if you have any query

Thanks

Comment: This works great.  Except, I can't get the max fields to stop at 10, it just keeps going and going.  Everything else works exactly how I want!

Comment: Hi Matt.I forget to check this limit.I have edited code could you please try above edited code and let me know if you have still facing any problem

Comment: Once you max out at 10, if you click "remove" it removes the row like I wanted, however, if you hit "Add More" again, it doesn't add anymore.  Also, if you click "No" it hides everything fine, but when you click "Yes", then "Add More"  nothing happens.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Once I click "remove", I decrease the counter, allowing me to add another row. When you click "No", I reset the counter to 0, allowing me to add up to 10 more textboxes to replace the max of 10 I removed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the `click()` function on `test_yes` and `test_add` compounding everytime you click yes.

Each time you click yes it adds another event on the add button, which in result, adds more text boxes as it should, but it only needs one.  You need to separate this so it doesn't do this.  Also, you may want to consider making a fiddle, it literally took me 30 seconds.

Edit:

Here is a quick fix. Mark it loaded with a class `.loaded` then use `:not(.loaded)` to make sure it doesn't reinitialize your click function over and over again.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7t8fgnrw/1/

Honestly though, it's not how I would've done it. I would have already made the form, and just use the yes/no to hide/show and that's it. I don't see why you need to combine functionality of your yes/no and the inputs/add/remove, when it can be kept separate and modular, as all code is commonly.

Comment: This works fine, except if I max out the fields it stops at 10, which is great, but if I click "remove", I can't add it back.  If I only go to 7 fields, and click "No" then try to add the textfields back, it only lets me add 3 more

Answer (score 0):

Using the example -sagar umaretiya- provided, I was able to figure out how to get it to work as I wanted (please see my last comment on -sagar umaretiya- answer.  Below is the updated working code that does exactly everything I wanted.  Thank you to everyone who helped me find a great working solution for this issue.  I know it's confusing for my reasons of doing it this way, and the pickiness of the functions I needed for it, but I appreciate everyone's input.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>

  <style>
     .inp {
        width:40%;
    }

    .remove {
        float:right;
        color:blue;
        font-size:10px;
        text-decoration:underline;
        cursor:pointer;
        background:#FFF;
    }
  </style>

  <script>

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.test_list').hide();


        $('#test_yes').click(function(){
            $('.test_list').show();
        });


            var test_max_fields = 10;
            var test_x = 0;

            $('#test_add').click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();

                if(test_x < test_max_fields){
                    test_x++;
                    var inps = $('#test_wrapper >div:last').data('count')+1 || 0;
                    $('#test_wrapper').append('<div class="test" data-count="'+inps+'"><input type="text" name="test_textbox_1" id="test_textbox_1'+inps+'" class="inp"/> $<input type="text" name="test_textbox_2" id="test_textbox_2'+inps+'" class="inp"/><a class=remove>Remove</a><br><br></div>');

                }
                else {
                    var inps = "";
                }
            });

            $('#test_wrapper').on('click' , 'a.remove' ,function(){
                test_x--;
                $(this).closest('div').remove();
            });


        $('#test_no').click(function() {
            test_x = 0;
           $('#test_wrapper').empty();
            $('.test_list').hide();
        });
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table>
    <tr class="test_main">
        <td>
            Do you want to test this?
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="test_check" id="test_yes" value="Yes">
            <label>No</label>
            <input type="radio" name="test_check" id="test_no" value="No">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test_list" style="line-height:1em;">
        <td>
            Press the ADD MORE button
        </td>
        <td>
            Textbox 1 &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; Textbox 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test_list" style="line-height:1em;">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="test_wrapper">                        
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test_list">
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="test_add">Add More</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tabel>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to decrease the counter. It is only increased as soon as I can See.

Comment: No counter issue here, its an event one